# iOS should I use UILabel for a large text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, user-interface

I am loading a text from an external API. The text is about 1000 - 3000 character.

Would a UILabel be good to hold this big text?

I already have my view wrapped inside a scroll view. So I was thinking of checking the height of the label when it has finished getting the text from the API, then calculate and set a new heigh on the scroll view.

I only want to display a static text, but with the function that will let the user to hold-copy a selection of the text.

Is a UILabel able to hold a text this big, or should I use a text view which has scrolling/editing disabled?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: user  uitextview for that

Comment: use UITextView for that

Comment: UITextView with scrolling/ editing will do a great job...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Apple's Text Programming Guide for iOS, `UILabel` defines a label, which displays a static text string.
`UITextField` defines a text field, which displays a single line of editable text.
`UITextView` defines a text view, which displays multiple lines of editable text.
Although these classes actually can support the display of arbitrary amounts of text, labels and text fields are intended to be used for relatively small amounts of text, typically a single line. Text views, on the other hand, are meant to display large amounts of text.

For more information please check: [Text Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingTextClasses/UsingTextClasses.html)

Comment: Why bother placing static text as a label in a scroll view at all when a `UItextView` is much more convenient for both situations? `UITextView` editing can be set to no

Comment: @JSA986 : Seeing your comment I searched a lot to understand the difference between the UILabel and UITextfield. Now I feels that my answer is wrong. So I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Great Vishnu,  hope it provided some useful info